# Magento 2 add form for the grid

Tags: magento-2.1

I have created product grid under customer view tab using below URL as a reference

http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-backend-create-custom-tab-in-customer-view-and-load-grid-inside-admin

I have added checkboxes to every item in the grid.

Now I want to save selected products to the customer account in a custom table. For this, I need to add the grid under a form.

So can anyone has an idea on how to add form to the grid.